# Issue with RazorEngine, Templates and email addresses

Tags: c#, razor, razorengine

Hoping someone can help with this.  It's causing me a real headache.

RazorEngine is throwing an odd error whenever one of my templates contains an email address that contains a hyphen at the end of the user part of the address (e.g. user-@domain.com).  The error is long, and has great explanations about why dynamic models don't work etc., however, the relevant part is

```
The name 'domain' does not exist in the current context.
```

I don't get this with the same template when I change the email address to one that does not have the same -@ structure, so it's definitely something to do with how RazorEngine is parsing that.  It seems that particular sequence leads RazorEngine to read the @ as the start of a razor command.

I've tried replacing the '-' with the HTML entity &#45; but the result is the same.  Has anyone else seen this or does anyone know of any other workarounds I could try?

Comment: Please show an example of how this is being used.  Is the email address typed directly into the template or being passed in as part of the model?  Code helps.

Comment: This particular example uses the email address being typed directly into the template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is not JUST the hyphen, the issue is the -@ symbol. It is translating that as if you were passing the variable "domain" in your model, can't find it and freaks out. You will need to escape it which there are several ways of doing so, perhaps if you show your code then we could suggest which route to take. Most commonly this is solved by using something like @Html.Raw("treaviseacton-@gmail.com")

I can find comments and documentation everywhere on things like using underscores for html data attributes (ie data-test should be written in razor as data_test) but for the life of me I have never been able to find any documentation anywhere on why the hyphen is treated the way it is.

Comment: Hi Travis, as I said in my original post, if I remove the hyphen, the template compiles and runs correctly.  It's not a problem just with the @ it's specifically when it's combined with a preceding hyphen, but you're spot on with the underlying problem.  I've tried wrapping the address in Html.Raw, and various ways of escaping the hyphen this morning.  I'll try the same to escape the @, but doesn't look hopeful.  May have to resort to old-school string concatenation to work around it.

Comment: Hi Travis, that nailed it.  Escaping the @ works whether there's a hyphen there or not, not escaping it only works when there's no hyphen.  I won't pretend to get why the hyphen makes a difference, but I'll take the fix.